# How to calculate phase shift between two shifted wave signals in C

Tags: c

I'm comparing two different phase shifted wave signals with same frequency, my first task is to measure phase shift angle between two signals in **C language**.
Actually i'm from IC field and don't have much idea about programming language, but i'm currently learning C for that.

I'd write a code for Correlation Co-efficient for finding a time delay.
but its shows an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj3E6.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    bool True  =  1; //for sqr wave conversion
    bool False =  0 ;
    int n[10],m[10] ; // n is an array of 10 integers (as of now assuming some value)
    int i1, i2,x,y ;
    int r,xx[10],xy[10],yy[10],nr=0,dr_1=0,dr_2=0,dr_3=0,dr=0;
    int sum_y=0,sum_yy=0,sum_xy=0,sum_x=0,sum_xx=0;
    int  i, h=10;


    /* initialize elements1 of array n to 0 */
    for (i1=0;i1<10;i1++)
    {
        n[i1] = i1+1; // set an element at location i to 10
    }
     /* initialize elements2 of array n to 0 */
    for (i2=0; i2<10; i2++)
    {
        m[i2] = i2+5;

    }

    //output of each array element
    for (x=0 ;x<10; x++)
    {
             if (x%2 == 0) //sqr wave coversion
              {
         True = 1 ;
               }

              else
              {
         False = 0 ;
              }

        printf("element1 [%d] = %d\n" , x, n[x]);

    }
    for (y=0 ; y<10; y++)
    {
            if (y%2 == 0) //sqr wave
            {
             False  = 0;
            }

            else

            {
             True = 1;
            }


        printf("element2 [%d] = %d\n" , y, m[y]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
     xx[i]= x[i]*x[i];
     yy[i]= y[i]*y[i];
    }
     for(i=0;i<h;i++)
    {
     sum_x+=x[i];
     sum_y+=y[i];
     sum_xx+= xx[i];
     sum_yy+=yy[i];
     sum_xy+= x[i]*y[i];
    }
    hr=(h*sum_xy)-(sum_x*sum_y);
    int sum_x2=sum_x*sum_x;
    int sum_y2=sum_y*sum_y;
    dr_1=(h*sum_xx)-sum_x2;
    dr_2=(h*sum_yy)-sum_y2;
    dr_3=dr_1*dr_2;
    dr=sqrt(dr_3);
    r=(hr/dr);
    printf("Total Numbers:%d\nCorrelation Coefficient:%.2f",h,r);
    return 0;
}
```

Code is still incomplete for finding a phase angle , but as of now i'm facing this error.[added snapshot]

PS: **I'd already done this task on H/W platform.**

Comment: Hi, this question is not really [on-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you are stuck on some specific part of your code, post it. If you are asking for a general algorithm, rephrase the question and add some information about what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: If you are from hardware land, you probably know PLLs.

Comment: Do you know the equation(s) to compute the value?

Comment: Hi,  @Groo yes i already did some work on this code ..like (1) first make a array for those signals data the i converted into a square wave for calculating a angle between waves, now i'm stuck in phase angle ... task which is my last thing probably i guess... That's why i'm saying  suggest me some idea.

Comment: I assume you know the phase difference equation? [A*sin(wt + x) for sin waves] - try it yourself in code first and see if you get expected results.. if not then post the code here and we can help debug the issue in your implementation :)

Comment: @Zenith: what you're trying to do is find [phase correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation), it's generally done [using FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591631/69809). Meaning that your first step would be to implement FFT in C, or find an existing implementation.

Comment: hey @james Thanks for the replay.. okay i'll go with this, and get back to here.

Comment: great - be sure to describe which type of waves you have (sine, cosine, etc) and the equation itself for the people who don't have background knowledge in this area

Comment: @Groo Actually working on project for some real time streaming ..so for that have to calculate power, and for power i want some sine , cos, tan and phase value ..this thing i want to implement on software platform. so i'm writing a code logic for this. and stuck at some point (measuring phase angle through C.)

Comment: @Zenith If you're comfortable with HW solutions you likely had exposure to the DFT in your classes; take the DFT of your signals and you can find relative phases (or even better, DFT of the cross-correlation). One of my projects right now deals with similar issues (phase detection for baseband-OFDM) and we start with a DFT, just like you should here.

Comment: Hiii, @nanofarad Thanks alot for your precious suggestion. Yes , now i have an idea about that ..i m trying with cross- correlation with 2d-array pattern identification.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's my bad ..here i replaced x and y with n and m , which is an **array**.
I sorted out this error:)